# Variable tree : how to get .operator functions for a variable in SonarQube

Tags: java, sonarqube

I want a custom rule which reports issue for following scenario:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private void getLength() {
        StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        int length = strBuffer.toString().length(); // I want issue to be reported on this line for "strBuffer.toString().length();"
    }
}
```

What I have so far is :

```
@Override
public void visitMemberSelectExpression(MemberSelectExpressionTree tree) {
    System.out.println("MEMBERSELECTEXPRESSIONTREE--" + tree.identifier().identifierToken().text() + "--symbol name --" + tree.identifier().symbolType().name());
    if (tree.is(Kind.METHOD_INVOCATION)) {
        System.out.println("**************Method Invocation**********" + tree.identifier().symbolType().name());
        if (tree.identifier().identifierToken().text().equalsIgnoreCase("toString")) {
            System.out.println("**************Method Invocation**********tostring");
        }
    }
    super.visitMemberSelectExpression(tree);
}
```

But above code is not working..Please guide me how to accopmlish this? 
Which tree (ExpressionTree, VariablTree, BinaryExpressionTree or some other) shall I use to get that token after dot operator (`.`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strBuffer.toString().length();` is not a binaryExpression it is a method invocation tree.

. is not an operator per say and this seems to be completely unrelated to variableTree (which is the syntax tree part of the *declaration* of the variable, not its usage)

This method invocation tree has a methodSelect field that is a memberSelectExpression (a tree made of an identifier and an expression) with identifier `length` and expression that is a method invocation tree (`strBuffer.toString()`) which has a methodSelect field that is a member select expression as well with identifier `toString` and expression that is an identifier tree (`strBuffer`)

Then I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but if you want to detect some method invocation you can rely on semantic analysis (using symbols API) and there is a rule template to detect specific method invocations.

[EDIT]

In order to detect that you have those two successive calls in one expression what I would do is the following :

Detect calls to the length() method of `java.lang.String` then check that this method invocation has a methodSelect that is a method invocation (`methodSelect.is(Tree.Kind.METHOD_INVOCATION)`) and check that this method invocation is an invocation of the `toString` method of a StringBuffer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..can u please provide any link which shows rule template to detect specific method invocation..also please see the edit i made to question ..m wondering how can i use instanceof string buffer in this memberselectExpression

Comment: There you go for rule template : http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS2253 (no need to do any code for those). I don't get your last question in comment

Comment: please see the edit in my question and suggest how can i get if the given symbol is string buffer and if the given identifier is string buffer then if it has used toString.length(); in a single statement ..while looking on printed result of my code i see length and to string is given one after another ..how to find that these both are part of same expression ?

Comment: It can't. Your tree in this case is a memberselectExpressionTree which has the kind MEMBER_SELECT. Check the expression field of this tree not the tree itself.

Comment: Thanks It helped .. :)